# How would I create a Visual Studio External tool to run the 'Add Items to Folder...' TFS command?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

I would like to create an external tool that can execute the TFS 'Add Items to Folder...' command.

How can I do this?

Comment: Instead of creating a tool for this, the answer below directs you to the procedure of adding an existing tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tools -> External Tools -> Add

- Title: Add Documents
- Command: c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\professional\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer\tf.exe
- Arguments: add *.* /recursive
- Initial Directory: C:\path_to_my_directory

[Add document to TFS external tool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UVVRy.png)